# What is the maximum number of pieces of pizza possible when it is cut with 5 straight line cuts (the lines don't go through the center of the pizza.)?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the maximum number of pieces of pizza possible when cut with 5 straight lines, none of which pass through the center of the pizza?

Comment: Are you allowed to move the pieces between cuts? Are you essentially thinking of cutting a circle (ie a dissection of the pizza as a two-dimensional object), or is eg a horizontal cut allowed?

Comment: @MarkBennet I would hate to be the kid who was given the bottom slice... all dough and no toppings... not even sauce.

Comment: I don't think i am allowed to move the pieces between the cuts but u can try? No, I am not essentially thinking of cutting a circle? A horizontal cut can be alowed

Comment: I would hate to be the kid to??

Comment: I believe you are talking about the [Lazy Caterer's Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer%27s_sequence).  If not and you are allowed to move pieces, then after each cut, stack the resulting pieces and cut down on those for the next, you'll double the total number of pieces each time.  If you aren't allowed to move pieces but horizontal cuts are allowed or cuts at other angles... then it is whatever the three-dimensional analogue of the lazy caterer's sequence is.

Comment: What does this have to do with complex multiplication?

Comment: Absolutely nothing.  Though, I'm failing to remember what I would describe this problem as officially... algebraic-topology?  I recall proving the ham-sandwich theorem there which is somewhat similar in flavor, though this ought to be provable without the language of algebraic topology.  "Discrete mathematics" seems too broad.  Combinatorics might actually fit once you make the connection between the resulting regions consisting of places where one line intersects another or where multiple lines intersect one another...

Comment: @JMoravitz Combinatorics, I would say.

Comment: @JMoravitz That's pure mathematics in a nutshell ...

Comment: As an aside, the three-dimensional analogue of the lazy caterer's sequence appears to be called the sequence of [Cake Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cake_number).

Comment: Why restrict lines from the center?  That condition is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

I get $16$ pieces, based on a star:

[image]

Each added line cuts every prior line (and circumference)... a greedy algorithm.  The fact that each region is convex means that you cannot do better than that.

If you analyze it by counting the number of pieces added by each cut, you find that the number of pieces, $p$, as a function of number of cuts, $n$, is:

$$p(n) = 1 + \frac{n + n^2}{2}$$

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccccc}
 n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
 p & 1 & 2 & 4 & 7 & 11 & 16 & 22 & 29 & 37 & 46 & 56 \\
\end{array}
$$

---

Note:  the problem constraint that lines not pass through the center of the pizza is irrelevant.

Comment: While it is in fact the maximum, this doesn't give adequate information how to prove that it is the maximum.  What evidence is there to suggest that this particular collection of edges was the optimal solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic is the following:
 Every next line should cross all the previous ones separately.
 If so, then the answer is 16.

Let the number of lines be $L$ and the maximum number of sections be $S$. 
 I suggest the following pattern(which is really interesting):
$$L \quad S$$
$$______$$
 $$1 \quad 2$$ 
$$2 \quad  4$$
$$3 \quad 7$$
$$4 \quad 11$$
$$5 \quad 16$$
       $$...$$
 Notice that $ S_{n+1} = S_n +L_{n+1} .$
 $$\  $$ I know that this doesn't provide a proof, but it is interesting.

Comment: While true, that doesn't explain how to calculate the value of $16$.

Comment: I'm working on it now.

Comment: What is the difference between your $L_{n+1}$ and $n+1$??

Comment: No difference actually.